# problem with a HashSet's Iterator

Tags: java, generics, iterator, hashset, downcast

I'm trying to see if HashSet would be the solution for my next project so i'm doing some very easy test to check functionalities.
I have a simple class `Klant`:

```
public class Klant {
    private int klantNummer;

    public Klant(int nummer) {
        this.klantNummer = nummer;
    }

    public int getKlantNummer() {
        return this.klantNummer;
    }
}
```

and a class with through composition uses a `HashSet`

```
public class MySet<Klant> { 
    private Collection<Klant> mySet = null;

    public MySet() {
        mySet=new HashSet<Klant>();
    }

    public void add(Klant elem) {
        mySet.add(elem);
    }

    public void toon() {
        Iterator<Klant> i = mySet.iterator();   
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Klant k = i.next();
            System.out.println(k.);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the method `toon()` 
Basically even though i specify that the Iterator will contain Klant objects `<Klant>`
The local `k` object does not provide me with the `getKlantNummer()` mthod defined in `Klant`
The `k` object its still an `Object` instance, and even by casting it with:

```
Object k = (Klant)i.next();
```

it won't work.
Down-casting is dangerous, but as far as i remember it is not prohibited.

Any advice?

Comment: I recommend using `for( Klant k : mySet )`

Comment: Thank you Chris, thats indeed better

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your class definition, you have

```
public class MySet<Klant> {
```

That `Klant` is being interpreted as a type parameter for your class (just like `E` is for `Collection` or `K` and `V` are for `Map`).  It is overriding your actual class `Klant` when you subsequently use it within `MySet`, and since its erasure is `Object` (as you specified no upper bound) a variable of type `Klant` within your `MySet` class will only see `Object`'s methods.  Remove the type parameter and use

```
public class MySet {
```

and you should be good.