# Making my dictionary search more efficient

Tags: java, dictionary, search, solver, boggle

I created a boggle solver in Java and it takes around a minute and 30 seconds to solve a board and I'm convinced its because of the way I traverse through my dictionary. The idea is it checks to see if its a word and also to see if it is a valid prefix. if its a valid prefix it will return true so the program continues running. If it returns false then the program will stop running the course it is taking. I read about trie structures but I don't quite get how to implement them. Examples with written code a small explanation would be most appreciated

```
private ArrayList <String> dic = new ArrayList<String>(/*dictionary()*/);//my useable dictionary
private ArrayList <String> dicFinal = new ArrayList<String>();//all the words found
private ArrayList <String> checked = new ArrayList<String>();//all words that have   already been checked go here
public boolean CheckTest (String word)throws IOException{//if its impossible to create a word with the combination of letters then it returns false, 
    String backw=reverse(word);
    boolean isValid = true;     
    if (word.length()<=1){isValid = true;}
    else if (checked.contains(word)&&checked.contains(backw)){}
    else{
        boolean isWord=true;
        if(checked.contains(word)){}
        else if(dic.contains(word)==true){
            setCount(getCount()+1);
            dicFinal.add(word);
            dic.remove(word);
            isWord=true;
        }
        else
            isWord=false;
        if(checked.contains(backw)==true){}
        else if (dic.contains(backw)==true){
            setCount(getCount()+1);
            dicFinal.add(backw);
            dic.remove(word);
        }
        if(isWord==false){
            for(int i=0;i<dic.size();i++){
                if(word.length()<=dic.get(i).length()&&dic.get(i).substring(0, word.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(word.substring(0, word.length()))){
                    isValid=true;
                    i=dic.size();
                }
                else 
                    isValid=false;
            }
        }
    }
    checked.add(word);
    checked.add(backw);
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: It would be valuable to see the declarations for `dic` and `checked`. Also, if you could show some execution profile timings to confirm a) that this function is, in fact, taking the bulk of the execution time and b) which parts of this function are taking the bulk of the execution time, that would help you and us target the most promising areas for optimisation.

Comment: If it turns out that the dictionary accesses are, in fact, the bottleneck then there is a trie implementation in Java at http://www.superliminal.com/sources/TrieMap.java.html.

Comment: they are all arrayLists, I also don't know how to show execution profile timings because I am fairly new to Java/programming

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that the first thing to do would be to make `dic` and `checked` HashSets instead of ArrayLists, which will give you O(1) access time instead of O(N). If your supposition that these lookups are the key bottleneck is correct, your program's performance should improve enormously.

If that doesn't improve matters enough, it would be worth investing a few minutes in learning how to profile Java programs so that you can pinpoint where the problem lies.

Comment: I tried making them all hashsets but i couldnt figure out a way to get the string that was stored in the hashset. ArrayList's have the .get() method, and hashsets have an itorator but when i used it it returned nothing everytime. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you could show some succinct, self-contained code using a HashSet with an iterator to show how it is not behaving correctly (best to do this as a separate question), I or someone else might be able to help you with that. If you're looking for an example of how to do it, there is a brief example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235010/problem-with-a-hashsets-iterator.